# Dynamic gallery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How would you write the below code in jQuery?

I have the code working in php, it is to create a way of added a list item with light box and an image. Without having the write each img src and lightbox link out.

```
<?php

                        $images = range(1, 3);

                        $rowCount = 0;

                        foreach ($images as $image) {
                        // stripping stuff:
                        echo '<li class="search-dogs"';


                          echo '><a href="images/gallery/search-dogs/'.$image.'.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery]">
                              <img src="images/gallery/search-dogs/'.$image.'.jpg">
                            </a></li>';
                        }

       ?>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow *is not* a code conversion service.

Comment: The full answer was not required just some pointers or helpful information would be okay. breath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var images = [1,2,3];
 var rowCount = 0;
 var TargetElement = 'body'; //html tag, .classTag, #htmlElementId
 for(var image in images) {
     // stripping stuff:
      $(TargetElement).append('<li class="search-dogs"><a href="images/gallery/search-dogs/'+image+'.jpg" rel="lightbox[gallery]"><img src="images/gallery/search-dogs/'+image+'.jpg"></a></li>');
 }
```